# Error en depuración consumo Asíncrono con WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, spring, programación-reactiva, spring-webflux

Estoy implementando un consumo asíncrono de un microservicio A hacia un microservicio B utilizando WebFlux. Este proceso funciona correctamente: el microservicio A consume al microservicio B y no espera el resultado de este último para continuar con su propio flujo de ejecución.

Sin embargo, he observado un comportamiento inesperado durante la **depuración**: el microservicio B solo entra en modo de depuración después de que el microservicio A ha finalizado su ejecución. He intentado especificar el hilo en el que deseo que se realice el consumo desde el microservicio A, pero no he logrado que el microservicio B se ejecute simultáneamente con el microservicio A. ¿Es este comportamiento característico del depurador, es decir, en una ejecución normal, el microservicio B no debería esperar a que el microservicio A termine para iniciar su ejecución?

De antemano, gracias